# Problemas con actualización de Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Mi problema es que al tratar de actualizar la distribución de Ubuntu, o remover paquetes automáticamente, es decir, al usar cualquiera de estos dos comandos:

```
> sudo apt-get dist-update 
> sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: primer parte del error]

[image: última parte del mensaje en la consola]

El mensaje es mucho más largo, pero para no abrumar con tantas imágenes puse aquellas que me parecieron más relevantes.

Según el comando `lsb_release -a`, mis datos son:

```
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
> Release:  16.04
> Codename: xenial
```

... y con `uname -a` obtengo la siguiente info:

```
> Linux MiPC 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Pienso que el problema es una mala configuración de `dbus` o `whoopsie`, pero desconozco cómo solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya solucione el problema, aquí la cuestión:
Había instalado el Driver de la impresora ( Xerox phaser 3140) desde la web oficial y obviamente el Driver para Linux. Pero no tenía bien configurado el servicio de cups, por ende no me funciono, me olvidé de esto e investigando más todavía. me di cuenta de que smfpd era efectivamente lo que detenía las actualizaciones. Corrí el desinstalador del Driver que es un .sh que se desempaqueta cuando bajamos el archivo comprimido del mismo. Luego ejecute: 
Sudo apt-get autoremove
Acto seguido ejecute:
Sudo apt-get dist-update
Y se solucionó el problema. 
Muchas gracias a aquellos que aportaron con sus respuestas.Lamentablemente no tuve tiempo de verlas y solucióne el problema de esa manera. Gracias.
P.D.: además pude imprimir instalando los paquetes correspondientes de CUPS y luego instalando el Driver de la impresora. Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, esto me funcionó correctamente.

muchas gracias por las respuestas enviadas.

Comment: Por si no se entendió la secuencia fue: 1) instalo Driver de impresora 2) trato de actualizar y no puedo 3) posteo la pregunta aquí.... Me había olvidado del paso 1 por eso no lo mencioné en el post inicial.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el problema está en el demonio [`smfpd`](http://wp.libpf.com/?p=162). Desconozco el motivo exacto al cuál se debe esto, pero parece que eliminando el demonio se puede actualizar el sistema.

Para ello, primero realiza una copia de seguridad en caso de que no funcione poder restaurarlo:

```
sudo cp /etc/init.d/smfpd ~/smfpd
```

Para el demonio:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smfpd stop
```

Y elimínalo:

```
sudo rm /etc/init.d/smfpd
```

Una vez hecho, reinicia y vuelve a intentarlo. En caso de no funcionar, ya sabes que tienes el demonio en tu carpeta personal.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Actualizar una versión de Ubuntu a otra, no lo recomendaría. Primero porque para que funcione bien tendrías que haber tenido un sistema sin muchas modificación. Segundo no va a ser tan limpio. Si querés la versión posterior, recomiendo siempre una instalación limpia.
La experiencia que tengo, nunca me salio bien eso de actualizar una versión a otra en Ubuntu